# Print array into another array [Zend]

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I use Zend 1

**CONTROLLER:**

```
    public function insertarAction() {

        $entidades_salud = new Application_Model_DbTable_EntidadesSalud();
        $datos_entidades = $entidades_salud->buscarEntidades();
}
```

**MODEL:**

```
<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_EntidadesSalud extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'entidades_salud';
    protected $_primary = 'codigo_entidad_salud';

    public function buscarEntidades() {

        $consulta = $this->select()->from($this->_name);
        $query = $this->fetchAll($consulta)->toArray();
        return $query;

    }


}
```

**PRINT OF CONSULT [print_r($datos_entidades); - in controller]**

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [codigo_entidad_salud] => 1 [nombre_entidad] => SANITAS ) 
             [1] => Array ( [codigo_entidad_salud] => 3 [nombre_entidad] => wladfimir )
             [2] => Array ( [codigo_entidad_salud] => 4 [nombre_entidad] => Juli ))
no entraArray ( [controller] => beneficiarios [action] => insertar [module] => default )
```

According to the above result, I require print:

```
1 SANITAS
3 wladfimir
4 Juli
```

I think it should work with something like:

```
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos_entidades)){
                echo $row['codigo_entidad_salud'];
        echo $row['nombre_entidad'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting The results into array,
you can do what Rikesh Suggested as,

```
foreach($datos_entidades as $row){
    echo $row['codigo_entidad_salud'];
    echo $row['nombre_entidad'];
}
```

And you can pass $datos_entidades to `View Script`
as `$this->view->data= $datos_entidades;`

and you will be able to use,

```
foreach($this->data as $row){
    echo $row['codigo_entidad_salud'];
    echo $row['nombre_entidad'];
}
```

in your view script also,

an alternate approach,

You dont use `toArray()` in  `$query = $this->fetchAll($consulta)->toArray();`

just use,  `$query = $this->fetchAll($consulta);`

and you will be able access it like following,

```
foreach($datos_entidades as $row){
    echo $row->codigo_entidad_salud;
    echo $row->nombre_entidad;
}
```

and will be able to access same way in view script also.

Comment: well again as stated,it's more the zendish approach to use foreach then the array. but still your, choice.

Comment: In the view I need to do a select (HTML ListBox)  http://pastebin.com/WkSHtbpj But nothing appears if you select Stand no function, other data appears. @dragon-warrior

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop to iterate through an array.

```
foreach($datos_entidades as $row){
    echo $row['codigo_entidad_salud'];
    echo $row['nombre_entidad'];
}
```

**Note:** The display logic should fall into the view file, you should pass data to view & in view file you need loop to display the records.

Comment: Solved with:

 for($i=0;$i<count($datos_entidades);$i++)
 {
 
  print $datos_entidades[$i]['codigo_entidad_salud']."<br>";
  print $datos_entidades[$i]['nombre_entidad']."<br>"; 
        }

Comment: Foreach is better than for to iterate an array still it's upto you.

Comment: So I'm doing: http://pastebin.com/Brp2KDJw but does not work, there is no data http://i.imgur.com/O3BQ578.png